# Swift 3.0 - Vertical lines on TableViewCell for every CellIndentationLevel

Tags: swift, uitableview, comments, cell, indentation

I have an app that has a bunch of collapsible comments.

Each cell that holds a comment has an indentation cell and I would like to draw a vertical line the height of the cell for every indentation level. The end goal is to look something like this: [Taken from Reddit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npzRZ.png)

I tried to add a rectangle shaped view for every indent level in CellForRowAt but it would just keep adding onto itself whenever I scrolled out of view and back into it.

Currently I have it working in the "willDisplay cell" function but it only loads it when the ENTIRE cell is visible, not partially and it still has some issues of overlapping content with lines.

Here's my current code:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    for cell in commentTable.visibleCells {

        if cell.indentationLevel > 0 {
            for i in 1...cell.indentationLevel {
                let rect = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: i * 15, y: 0, width: 1, height: Int(cell.bounds.height)))
                cell.addSubview(rect)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do this preferably in cellForRowAt function, or the simplest and most efficient way to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in cellForRowAtIndexPath.  Note that you should not just add views to your cells without tracking them because the cells are reused (thats why its called dequeResuableCell).  Make a property called indentationViews and a function called setIndentationLevel.  In cellForRowAtIndexPath you call cell.setIndentationLevel (note that I have removed your if because for 0..

```
func setIndentationLevel(indentationLevel: Int) {
    for i in 0..<cell.indentationLevel {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: i * 15 + 15, y: 0, width: 1, height: Int(cell.bounds.height)))
        cell.addSubview(view)
        indentationViews.append(view)
    }
}
```

You also need to implement prepare for reuse to kill all of the views you just added before the cell gets used again:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
   indentationViews.forEach{$0.removeFromSuperview()}
   indentationViews.removeAll()
}
```

Comment: I tried adding that, but it seems to still not do it properly as I scroll up and down through the table. It adds more lines. Where exactly should I call the prepareForReuse, as it's not overriding any function?